# SQL Query to join item descriptions for 2 parts

Tags: mysql

This is my first post.  Sorry if redundant or not specific enough.

I am new-ish to SQL and may have over thought this into a mind block.

I have a table that has "parent_item_id" and "child_item_id" but no descriptions.  I was wanting to make a query to include descriptions for both those items.

My starting point was:

```
SELECT B.P_ITEM as Parent, I.description as P_desc, B.C_ITEM, I.description as C_desc
from boms B
left join items I on B.P_ITEM = I.item_id
```

I understand that will put the parent description in for both the parent and the child fields.

How do I create a query that will provide me descriptions for both the parent and child items in a row?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your bill of materials is really simple like this:

```
ID  p_item    c_item   quantity
1   1         500       1
2   1         600       4
```

Items table may have

```
ID  description
1   Big Computer
500 128GB SSD
600 2GB Memory
```

Your query will look like this:

```
select b.*, p.description, c.description
from bom b
inner join items p on p.id = b.p_item
inner join items c on c.id = b.c_item
```

Result:

```
| id | p_item | c_item | quantity |  description | description |
|----|--------|--------|----------|--------------|-------------|
|  1 |      1 |    500 |        1 | Big Computer |    128G SSD |
|  2 |      1 |    600 |        4 | Big Computer |  2GB Memory |
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e07/1

Comment: Thank you, that is easy solution and works like a champ.   I will have to remember inner joins!